# Why aren't my headers/footers appearing in CiviMail documents?

Tags: civimail

CiviMail is not including headers/footers in this newbie's newsletter. I think I've mis-configured something. I am expecting to see a tab in the Define Mailing menu.
[image]

The default headers and footers are unchanged from our original installation and set as "default" and enabled in Administer>CiviMail>Headers Footers and Automated Mailings. But they aren't included in any mailings.
CiviCRM 5.38.0 on Wordpress

Comment: I think I can replicate what you are seeing on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/a/#/mailing/1 but i could only do so by disabling the Header and Footer https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/component?reset=1

Comment: but you have clearly stated both yours are enabled. odd.

Comment: Confirmed: all the default headers and footers are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that the options for Headers and Footers appear properly if I used the traditional CiviCRM templates. I should have mentioned that I was using the Mosaico templates which were recommended to me. So I have a work-around.

Comment: oh. I wondered about that but your screenshot matched what is shown on Traditional ones - hence i didn't ask if you were using Mosaico or not - now realise that this part of the interface is same for both. For mosaico, yep the traditional Header/Footers do not apply